# How to decrypt string( which is encrypted by java) by python in AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding?

Tags: java, python, cryptography, aes

I am doing a django project which a part involving decrypt the json playload and the data inside is encrypted by java in ASE/ECB/PKCS5Padding. So I am trying to get the encrypted string and put it in python script to see whether it is possible to decrypt it back the original string. Here is the [Code](https://github.com/williamwhw326/AESUtiles/blob/master/Enc.java) of en/decryption in java.

And this is my python version:

```
class AESCipher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.key = '9sdf3jkkjsdfUUJH'

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        raw = pad(raw)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_ECB)
        enc_str = cipher.encrypt(raw)
        str_64 = base64.b64encode(enc_str)
        return(str_64.decode())


    def decrypt(self, enc):
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_ECB)
        #enc += (len(enc) % 4) * '='
        decrypt_bytes = base64.b64decode(enc)
        dec = cipher.decrypt(decrypt_bytes)
        try:
            result = \
            re.compile('[\\x00-\\x08\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\n\r\t]').sub('',\
                                     dec.decode())
        except Exception:
            result = 'fail'
        return(result)
```

However, it can only do a normal en/decryption but can't decrypt the java one. I guess its because of the getSecretKey() method in java, but I am not good in java and have no idea what is it. May I ask still is it possible to decrypt the string encrypted by java? Thanks

Comment: Please add the errors you get to the question.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right key to decrypt ?

Comment: @Roshith Yes, I wrote the basis AES en/decryption script in java and python. Both return the same result. However, if I use the script in the GitHub link to en/decrypt the same string by the same key, the return changed. Probably because the getSecretKey(key) changed the key in a unknown way. How can I write the same getSecretKey(key) by Python? I have done many research on google but seems no one tried to do that.